# How to narrow cast parent class to child class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, casting

I am creating a University Management system where I have a Database class where I store the currentUser object of class User. Upon a successful login currentUser object becomes a Student or a Teacher object (which are User's children). But when I try to call Student's method on the currentUser object it doesn't work.

here is the object currentUser:
`public static User currentUser;`
so the currentUser is not initialized and I don't want to downCast it at this stage,

this is how I authorize a user:
`

```
if(student.getLogin().equals(login) && student.getPassword().equals(password)) {
                    currentUser = student;
                    isLogedIn = true;
                }
```

`

I tried type casting User to Student like this:
`

```
currentUser = student;
                    currentUser = (Student) currentUser;
```

`
but I still can't call Student methods on currentUser. How can I fix it?

Comment: You'll need to introduce a new variable of with the type you want to use: `Student student = (Student) currentUser;`, then you can call Student methods on it. Or do it inline without declaring a new variable like `((Student) currentUser).someMethodOfStudent();` You can never call any methods on `User currentUser` that don't belong to class `User` as long as it is declared as `User`.

Comment: Is there any way I can store Student object into the initial User variable?

Comment: Casting is not magical and does not change what an object intrinsically is, just what the compiler thinks that it is. You should give your classes copy constructors so that new objects of the appropriate classes can be made from the old.

Comment: If the casting works (which I assume) then you already do that. Casting wouldn't work if the object wouldn't be a Student already. The quesiton I would like to ask you is why you declared the type as `User` at all if you seem to always want to use `Student` and its methods? Why not `Student currentUser` and spare yourself all that casting trouble if all your users are Students anyway?

Comment: Oh, I understood what you were saying, now I get it. Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currentUser` is a variable of type `User`, so you can only use its (and its parents') method through it.

You could cast the actual instance to a `Student` and store it in a temporary variable of that type to use `Student`'s methods:

```java
Student currentStudent = (Student) currentUser;
currentStudent.someStudentMethod();
```

Of course, you can also omit the storing and call the method directly on the cast instance:

```java
((Student) currentUser).someStudentMethod();
```